# Android. that this does not work well? is a bug? SetMargins

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

By setting the margins to zero the image fills the screen. But to set the margins to one hundred, it fits all right except the right side. Why do it?

---

```
ImageView imagen = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
relative.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutImagenClicker = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
layoutImagenClicker.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
imagen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.barra_seek_bar);
imagen.setLayoutParams(layoutImagenClicker);
rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rl.addView(imagen);
relative.addView(rl);
setContentView(relative);
```

[image: paddins zero image]

---

```
ImageView imagen = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
relative.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutImagenClicker = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
layoutImagenClicker.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
imagen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.barra_seek_bar);
imagen.setLayoutParams(layoutImagenClicker);
rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rl.addView(imagen);
relative.addView(rl);
setContentView(relative);
```

[image: paddins image one hundred]

---

**different margins with the same padding?**

```
layoutImagenClicker.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
layoutImagenClicker.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);
```

---

watch this!

```
layoutImagenClicker.setMargins(100, 100, 200, 100);
```

[image: a busy cat]

The same result set margin right 100 or 200. is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting padding on the RelativeLayout wrapper, and than remove the margin on the imageview. As to your original question, I have no idea why it gets messed up, but moving from margins to paddings is what I always prefer...

```
ImageView imagen = new ImageView(this);
RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
        (LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

// Padding on the RelativeLayout
relative.setPadding(100,100,100,100);

relative.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutImagenClicker = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
         (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

// Remove the margin on the child
//layoutImagenClicker.setMargins(100, 100, 100, 100);


imagen.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.barra_seek_bar);
imagen.setLayoutParams(layoutImagenClicker);
rl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams    (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
rl.addView(imagen);
relative.addView(rl);
setContentView(relative);
```

Good luck